# WCF Remove xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/"

Tags: c#, .net, xml, wcf, soap

I have a problem getting a client to integrate with my system.  I think I have narrowed the problem.  The client is sending over an xml message and my system is setup to accept an xml message; however it is expecting it in certain format. The client has expressed a desire for me to setup the format on my end to accept theirs.

This is the clients message:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"  
                  xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
            <soapenv:Header/>
            <soapenv:Body>
               <NewOrder>
                  <Message id="d3a39c31-cc9f-4331-ad13-be74522df6eb">
                     <Header>
                        <LoginAccountIdentifier>Blank</LoginAccountIdentifier>
                        <LoginAccountPassword>password</LoginAccountPassword>
                     </Header>
```

I noticed that my expected format is excepting the prefix tem: on the nodes.

This is expected message:

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                      xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:NewOrder>
         <tem:Message id="d3a39c31-cc9f-4331-ad13-be74522df6eb ">
            <Header>
               <LoginAccountIdentifier>Blank</LoginAccountIdentifier>
               <LoginAccountPassword>password</LoginAccountPassword>
            </Header>
```

I believe that if I can remove the prefix then this should match up the client's message with expected message.  The problem is where do I remove the prefix "< tem:"; furthermore, how do I prevent this variable xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" from showing up in my document?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue too long ago.  Try using this:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
```

Apparently, the prefix is determined by the namespace so if you want it removed then this would be the way to go.

Good luck!

Comment: So, this is actually the answer to a much larger problem. I have a service project which is used as a WCF reference AND a binary reference in other projects.. because of the location of some of these sites, i have to expose different services for different applications, which means that the namespace will change based on where it's used. Setting the blank namespace allows me to set the URI via the web config only..

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that's from the WebService.svc (or .asmx) class having a 

`[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]`

attribute at the top of the class definition.  Removing this (or setting it to an appropriate value) should remedy the problem.